# Oculus integration Custom hand movements in my VR Unity project not working on my system

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am working in unity on creating a application for the the Quest VR system. (Quest2) and added the Oculus Integration Package to my project. (While following an online course)

When I try and use any of the custom hands provided in the package, or run any of the example scenes that use them, the finger movements follow my controller grip presses (hand trigger) perfectly making a semi fist with the bottom 3 fingers, but the index trigger presses do not seem to cause any animation. Neither does a thumb press.

[image]

I have added a crude Log to show the triggers are being picked up by the system, but the animation is not showing.

What makes this very vexing as I shared my project with the course provider I was following and it worked perfectly for him.

So the problem is on my system somewhere..

Implementing the same from scratch using the XRInteraction toolkit system works perfectly btw. But the Oculus provided system does not.

If anyone has any ideas on where to even begin looking for the problem I would appreciate it  greatly.

Happy to share system details but not even sure which details would be relevant :)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution?